# Enabling SSL on kafka clients

Tags: security, ssl, apache-kafka

We have a Kafka cluster and various producers and consumers running across at least 5 differe servers. I have been asked to secure Kafka environment using SSL. I have configured SSL on brokers, now it's time to secure clients. So in the document it's mentioned that below config needs to be placed in producer/consumer config

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

Now the problem is I have distributed producer and consumer application jars to different teams and they have deployed them on their application servers. How can I create truststore for all of them? Can anyone explain me this concept. In case clients run on hundreds of server how can one create truststore on each server? Please help.

Comment: take a look here: http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html